# Nested Collection View inside of table view cell swift iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am nesting a `collection view` inside of a table view cell. I need to implement a screen similar to that of the app store of netflix. **Where you have categories such as** [image]

I would need to load the data from a JSON, for instance - "Popular" may have 11 videos, "Action" May have 3 videos and "Adventures" may have 20. So inside each table view cell, that specific collection view would load a different number of collection view cells depending on how many videos are in each category (Popular, Action, Adventure), which will be displayed within its own respective horizontal collection view.

So far with my code i display each category title in the table view header. But within that category, inside the collection view *numberOfItemsInSection* and *cellForItemAt*, i can't find a way to load each collection view interdependently. For example, **collection view 1** that relates to Popular, should load 11 cells, **Collection View 2** which relates to Action should load 3 cells. Below is my code so far

**My TABLE VIEW METHODS WHICH ARE INSIDE OF VIEW CONTROLLER**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "categoriesCell") as? CategoriesTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    return arrayOfCategoryObjects[section].title
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return arrayOfCategoryObjects.count
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let cell = cell as? CategoriesTableViewCell {


        cell.moviesCollectionView.dataSource = self
        cell.moviesCollectionView.delegate = self

        cell.moviesCollectionView.reloadData()

    }
}
```

**MY TABLE VIEW CELL**

```
class CategoriesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var moviesCollectionView: UICollectionView!

}
```

**MY COLLECTION VIEW DELEGATES WHICH ARE ALSO INSIDE THE VIEW CONTROLLER**

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   // print(arrayOfCategoryObjects[section].movies[section])

    return arrayOfCategoryObjects[section].movies.count

  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "moviesCell", for: indexPath) as! MoviesCollectionViewCell

        cell.movieTitleLbl.text = arrayOfCategoryObjects[indexPath.item].movies[indexPath.item]

        return cell

  }
```

**MY COLLECTION VIEW CELL**

```
class MoviesCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var movieTitleLbl: UILabel!

}
```

Comment: [This](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/) is the best resource you will get on this topic. See if this helps you else will try to look into the lengthy question :P

Comment: @Josh thanks for the response. I have actually been looking at that already. however its not showing me a way to display a different number of collection view cells per table view cell. Right now, all of the collection view cells are displaying the same count. For example - i have 4 categories (which are table view cells) - and each category should display a diff number of collection view cells. but they all display 3 collection view cells

Comment: don't you think this is always same for you -     `return arrayOfCategoryObjects[section].movies.count` ?

Comment: ok, let me try to guide in an answer.

Comment: @CodingwhileLoading you do everything in code ( better) ? what is the exact problem ? at glance calling reloadData in willDisplay seems wrong. collectionView inside tableViewCell is just a view. think simple.

Comment: the arrayOfCategories is a category object that has a property "movies" which is an array of strings. So if there are 4 arrayOfCategories objects - that means there are 4 movie properties which are each an array of [String]. Based on that movie property- that should determine how many cells should be loaded into each collection view

Comment: @user1105951 where should i reload the data at then ?

Comment: even in the resource Josh add, it's seems in different place. BUT maybe I'm wrong. I don't want to confuse you.

Comment: please check the answer I have posted and proceed on the lines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set a tag for your `UICollectionView` as parent `UITableViewCell`'s `indexPath.section`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let cell = cell as? CategoriesTableViewCell {

        cell.moviesCollectionView.dataSource = self
        cell.moviesCollectionView.delegate = self
        cell.moviesCollectionView.tag = indexPath.section
        cell.moviesCollectionView.reloadData()

    }
}
```

and then in your UICollectionView's delegate:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return arrayOfCategoryObjects[collectionView.tag].movies.count

  }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "moviesCell", for: indexPath) as! MoviesCollectionViewCell

    cell.movieTitleLbl.text = arrayOfCategoryObjects[collectionView.tag].movies[indexPath.item]

    return cell

  }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you will try to implement right now and get back to you

Comment: i am still getting 3 collection view cells per row. The expected ouput should be 4 table view cells, and within each table view cell the number of collection view cells should be 3, 3, 5, 5. - Thats 3 collection view cells in the first table view cell, 3 in the 2nd table view cell, 5 in the third table view cell and 5 in the last table view cell

Comment: print the collectionView.tag in the second method above.

Comment: i just did and the output is 0

Comment: I think that means it is getting the tag of the first collection view (which is 0) and is stopping there

Comment: scroll and there will be more outputs. Please share your project repo. This should be a small fix.

Comment: output is still the same when scrolling- and okay will do right now

Comment: 404 Not found :)

Comment: i had to change from private to public. please try now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206603/discussion-between-josh-and-coding-while-loading).

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer helped me to fix problems with images in collectionView inside tableView. Didn't know that it's solving with tag.